# React Context API, updating context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I would like to set the context at runtime after some networking call is complete (only then do I know the value which needs to be accessible throughout my app), but I don't know how to persist this value.

I can update the context value like so:

```
<NetworkVersion.Provider value={{version: this.state.version}}>
```

where I can use the state of the component. This approach has been taken from the official React docs.

but I was surprised to find out that other Consumers of this Provider get the default value (an empty object) which was initialised in the React.createContext() call. Is there a way to update the Context at runtime and keep that value for the lifetime of the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your Context Consumer is a child of the associated Provider, otherwise it will just get the default value. See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer

You'd also be better to pass a primitive value - i.e.

`<NetworkVersion.Provider value={this.state.version}>`

or you may get unnecessary re-renders. See https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Comment: Thanks, never thought this question would end up getting answered

Answer (score -2):

A consumer must be a child of the provider to get the context. If it is impossible to make your consumer be a child of the provider, make a common parent be the provider and add a callback to the context to give consumers a possibility to change the context.

```js
const NetworkVersion = React.createContext({
    version: null,
    setVersion: version => {}
});

class Parent extends React.Component {
    state = {
        networkContext: {
            version: null,
            setVersion: version => this.setState({
                networkContext: {...this.state.networkContext, version}
            })
        }
    };

    render() {
        return <NetworkVersion.Provider value={this.state.networkContext}>
            <VersionGetter/>
            <VersionSetter/>
        </NetworkVersion.Provider>;
    }
}

function VersionGetter() {
    return <NetworkVersion.Consumer>
        {networkContext => (
            <div>Version: {networkContext.version}</div>
        )}
    </NetworkVersion.Consumer>;
}

function VersionSetter() {
    return <NetworkVersion.Consumer>
        {networkContext => (
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => networkContext.setVersion('1.0')}>Set version 1</button>
                <button onClick={() => networkContext.setVersion('2.0')}>Set version 2</button>
            </div>
        )}
    </NetworkVersion.Consumer>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent/>, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```